# np.array and shape of matrix problmes, why it does not show the shape of matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shapes

I need your help.
I expected the shape of matrix is (836, 651, 17), but it only shows (17, )
Here, 836 and 651 are rows and column respectively.
I attached the code down there. 
What I want to do is to stack up (856, 661) size matrix on and on, and the layers of matrix will be 17.
And I would like to label them or linked with continuous values.
Could you help me out???

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Apr 19 13:19:16 2020

@author: SONSANGWOO
"""
#Depth_model

import os
import glob
import numpy as np

#############################################################################
#####                           Read files of raster                    #####
#############################################################################
path ='./data/depth'

folders = []

#r=root, d=dirctories, f=files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    if not d:
        folders.append(r)

for f in folders:
    print(r)

def process(folders, skiprows) :

    listData = []

    for folder_name in folders:

        IsFile=(glob.glob(folder_name+"/*.*"))

        for file in IsFile:

            raster = np.loadtxt(file, skiprows=skiprows)
            raster_transpose = raster.transpose()
            listData.append(raster_transpose)


        print("FINISH" + folder_name)

        arrayData = np.array(listData)

    return arrayData

arrayRaster = process(folders, 6)

print("ArrayRaster : ", arrayRaster)
print("Shape : ", arrayRaster.shape)

np.save=('Depth_Raster.npy', arrayRaster)
```

And this is the log of simulation

```
runfile('C:/Users/SONSANGWOO/Desktop/paperwork/Code/19.04.2020.py', wdir='C:/Users/SONSANGWOO/Desktop/paperwork/Code')
./data/depth
FINISH./data/depth
ArrayRaster :  [array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ...,
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]])
 array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ...,
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]])
 array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ...,
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]])
 array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ...,
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]])
 array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ...,
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]])
 array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ...,
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]])
 array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ...,
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]])
 array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ...,
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]])
 array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ...,
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]])
 array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ...,
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]])
 array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ...,
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]])
 array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ...,
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]])
 array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ...,
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]])
 array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ...,
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]])
 array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ...,
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]])
 array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ...,
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]])
 array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ...,
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]])]
Shape :  (17,)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your shape issue; ">>> np.array([np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])]).shape" returns (2, 2, 2) on my computer. Can you try to build a minimal example?

Comment: it returns to me the same, but in the code, no.

Comment: do you want me to give you the input files? then I will share it with you
Go to the following link: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fYO0CyP9n9_arGbSnXdBYrYwVb2gW_Ui)

Comment: one or more of the `raster` arrays differs in shape.  The (17,) array is object dtype.